# Fragment hierarchy changes after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which contains 2 fragments. Fragment 1 is a listview and fragment 2 is a normal view which is presented when an item in the listview is tapped. Consequently, fragment 2 should always be above fragment 1. Most of the time when the device is rotated, the fragments are restored in the proper order. However sometimes fragment 1 is restored above fragment 2 - what could be the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the z-ordering has been messed by reloading.

Have you tried Views bringToFront() Method?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()